# Call duration from click on phone line

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, html

In my website I have a phone number, I want that when the visitor surf via iPhone, the phone number will be clickable, and the number of clicks will be counted. (I know how can I do it via google analitycs - using events)

I also want to know how mach time the call was. (Using js or PHP)

It is possible?

Comment: I dont know if it posible, so I didn't try anyting... I know that I should use <a href='tel:123456789'>Click</a>

Comment: This is not possible. The phone call itself is controlled by the phone's OS, and neither javascript nor PHP are able (nor should they be) to access any of that information.

Comment: He just wants to count the clicks on the links, not the actual number of phone calls

Comment: If the visitor click on the phone number, it opens a popup window to confirm the call, after the call finished, the user return to the webpage in safari. There is an option the detect this? (The returning) Using jQuery maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Links are links, they open up a protocol but they are still links. If you use Jquery and bind a CLICK event on your phone link, you can count the number of times it was clicked.

Just create a page that will respond to a counting mechanism such as an ajax page and store that call in a database...

Comment: As I said, I know how to do the counting.

Comment: Then if you know how to do it, why not try it, you are poluting this site, voting to close

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin, because he's also asking if there's a way to figure out how long the call took, and that question has not been answered.

Comment: Darn, didn't read that part correctly then

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to detect the length of a phone call using either JS or PHP (or any language), unless you detect the call itself with VOIP or something similar. That doesn't have anything to do with the link in the first place.

Detecting the clicks on the link is possible, see Dumoulin's answer.

Creating a link to a phone number can be done using this: `<a href="tel:5555555">call</a>`.

Comment: If the visitor click on the phone number, it opens a popup window to confirm the call, after the call finished, the user return to the webpage in safari. There is an option the detect this? (The returning)

Comment: No, as Safari is still active during that call. You can, however, have the user tap a button or something confirming he finished the call.

Comment: If i'm doing something like here http://jsfiddle.net/Z4j9K/. When the user is on phone call, the interval stop running, and when he cames back, the interval continues . How can I do something like this?